# Use variable in a octoberCMS rules

Tags: octobercms

I want to do something like that.

```
public $rules = [
    'nbre_employe_min' => 'numeric|min:(nbre_employe_max)',
    'nbre_employe_max' => 'numeric',
];
```

How can I do? Someone know?

Comment: How would you normally use variables in php? Assuming ``$nbre_employe_max`` is defined, this would be ``'numeric|min:' . $nbre_employe_max``.

Comment: I tried it but we can't use php variables when we initialize a public variable.

Comment: Right, just initialize it in the constructor then.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same question of me, I have the answers.

Nothing is build in, but custom validator can do it.

```
public function boot()
{
    Validator::extend('bigger', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        $min_field = $parameters[0];
        $data = $validator->getData();
        $min_value = $data[$min_field];
        return $value > $min_value;
    });
}
```

use like this

```
public $rules = [
    'min' => 'required',
    'max' => 'required|bigger:min'
];
```